# How can I force my browser to automatically redirect a certain website?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, firefox, browser, redirection

For example, I never want to visit jsfiddle.com. Whenever I type jsfiddle.com into my URL bar, the browser should automatically take me to jsfiddle.net

Is there a browser extension for this? Can this be done system-wide? (If I hack my `hosts` file will it work reliably?)

PS: Using Windows 7 and Chrome + Firefox (should work on both!)

Comment: You could manually override it in chrome by using [SQLite browser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) to alter the `Shortcut` file in your User Data directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Firefox you could try redirector: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/redirector/

Comment: Any suggestions for Chrome?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [dns-overrider](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dns-overrider/acmhaiiijfheggcaanjlgpampclpbnoh) Chrome extension.

> DNS Overrider allows you to replace a current hostname with an alias. Hostnames will be changed in tags like , , . Only hostnames with a specified alias will be replaced.
>
> Using DNS Overrider you can replace hostname on the fly without access to system settings such as hosts file. DNS Overrider enables you to select what rules to apply via the extension settings page.

Comment: DNS Overrider does not seem to work for addresses in the URL bar, though it works for URLs within the body of a page.